# Does DFW have moving walkways in any terminal?

Tags: airports, dfw

I didn't see any [moving walkways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_walkway) in DFW in Terminal C. Do they have any in any terminal? Seems like they ought to for an airport of it's size but maybe not..

Comment: Perhaps expand your question to all walk-free options in DFW? I'm sure there's something like a free shuttle for those with disabilities.

Comment: I took one there last year.  It was a private flight from KSEP to DFW and sadly I do not remember the terminal (or I would give an answer).

Comment: @JonathanReez - I think it does have carts that employees drive around but I was curious specifically about moving walkways. Personally, I think it could benefit from them if it doesn't have them but whatever lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a photo of walkways in the google map gallery, which shows a 360° view with a DFW sign visible.
https://goo.gl/maps/VELoZojtUZJ2

Judging from the escalators at either end of the walkway, this appears to be beneath the tarmac and used to connect between two terminals.